# NotificationListenerService called before Application.onCreate code

Tags: android, android-service, android-application-class, notification-listener

I have a `NotificationListenerService` implementation in my app.

It seems that certain things that I initialize in my `Application` class are not initialized when my `NotificationListenerService` runs.
Also, crashes are not coming into `Crashlytics`, but into `Google Play` instead, so I'm assuming the initialization of `crashlytics` isn't happening as well.

- Is a service class extending `NotificationListenerService` not being called in an app's process?
- Is it called outside of the `Application` context?

Simplified implementation of my code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Settings.init(this);
    }
}

public class MyNotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if (Settings.getSomething()) { // Crash! settings not initialized
                    ...
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: and what do simple `Log.d` say (in both `onCreate` methods)?

Comment: hmm... it seems this was a false alarm, almost all crashes come from a "Vivo 1601" device, so I'm guessing it's a device error, not some android/app issue.

Comment: I'll keep the question up here, in case other uses stumble upon this crash as well

Answer (score 1):

It seems ~95% of reported crashes in Google Play come from a device called Vivo 1601, so this is most likely a bad implementation of Android on the device, or a rooted device repeatedly crashing.

Since this is not Crashlytics, I can't tell how many unique users have reported this crash, but it is safe to say It's not an issue in Android or my app.